# install facebook login for Magento 1.9 CMS

Tags: php, facebook, magento, facebook-graph-api

For some reason I cannot for the life of me find a clear answer, tutorial, documentation, plugin or extension that could assist in integrating a simple facebook login for Magento CMS website. Any suggestions at approaching integrating a simple facebook login or facebook connect with Magento commerce CMS? Currently not custom Magento, just a straight fresh Magento CMS 1.9 installation, just would like to integrate Facebook login capabilities. This has been extremely straightforward with Wordpress and many other CMS's but cannot find information about Magento. The quickest solution would be most ideal, either recommended extension or manual tutorial. Thanks for any advice.

Cheers,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install this magento module for facebook login in magento https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/facebook-connect-and-like.html